# Define alias that references other aliases

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'd need to be able to define an alias in a Debian shell that includes other aliases, for a project I'm currently working on.

Let's look at a code example to make things more clear.

1. `alias foo=foo`
2. `alias bar=bar`

If I run `type foo` it returns `foo is aliased to 'foo'`, and `type bar` returns `bar is aliased to 'bar'`. Up to here all fine. Now, where I'm having the problem.

3. `alias foobar=$foo$bar`

Doesn't work. `type foobar` returns `foobar is aliased to ''`.

I've tried `alias foobar=${foo}${bar}` and it doesn't work either.

Once I get this working, in the final version I actually need some text in between the two aliases, imagine something like: `alias fooandbar=${foo}and${bar}`.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're confusing aliases and variables.  They're two different things.  You can't refer to aliases using the $xx syntax.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To reuse alias in another alias use:

```
foobar='foo;bar'
```

However I would suggest you to consider using shell function to get better control over this.

Comment: I tried `alias foobar='foo;bar'`, but when I run `type foobar` it returns `foobar is aliased to 'foo;bar'`

Comment: Yes that's correct. When you execute `foobar` it will execute `foo` first and then `bar`.

Answer (score 6):

Following @anubhava's sage advice:

```
foo() { echo foo; }
bar() { echo bar; }
foobar() { echo "$(foo)$(bar)"; }
fooandbar() { echo "$(foo)and$(bar)"; }
```

Spaces and semicolons inside `{}` are required there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of alias that i'm using

```
#clear
alias cls='clear; ls'
alias ccls='cd; cls' # used alias cls
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this in csh and it worked for me :

alias new_alias 'vi old_alias'

Comment: What exactly does your example do? If I copy your example to my csh and run it, the alias would open a file called 'old_alias'