# tee >(bash) to use predefined aliases

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, alias

My requirement is a lot similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500481/define-alias-that-references-other-aliases).
I wrote a command `cat $HOME/.zsh_history | sort | uniq | fzf | tr ";" "\n" | grep "^[^:]" |tee >(bash)` which let's me browse through my history and execute the selection. but the problem here is that it doesn't work well with other aliases.
For example, i have `alias cls=clear`.
Executing `cls` using my command won't work. It gives an error saying
`bash: line 1: cls: command not found`.

The solution stated in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500481/define-alias-that-references-other-aliases) quite doesn't meet my use case.

1. All my aliases are saved in `$HOME/.bash_aliases`
2. I tried to replace `tee >(bash)` with `bash` but that didn't work either. (The reason I used tee instead of piping to bash directly is to print the command before executing).
3. Piping it through `zsh` instead of `bash` gives the same error `zsh: command not found: cls`

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to install fzf to fully replicate your actions.

However, looking at the code segment  **|tee >(bash)**  , what I see that is wrong there ... is that you should replace the "**>**" by a pipe (**|**), because "bash" is a process, *not a file-specification.*

Also, there should be **no need for the round brackets** around the bash call.